# Making a checkerboard-style with graphics (java applet)

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d, drawimage

OK so, I am making an applet that paints 32x32 square tiles (to make a map) and my problem is that they are going diagonally when I want them to go 8 by 8 (hence the way the array is shaped 8 by 8). So... how do I fix this?

Thanks. Anyway, since the code bbcode is being a butthead... here is the pastebin URL :-)

http://www.danflow.pastebin.com/kAUEpg1E

And here is the problem:

[image: It's not the way I want it]

I want it 8 by 8... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
g.drawImage(theTile, 32*i,32*i, this);
```

In order to draw it 8x8, you'll probably want to change it to something like

```
g.drawImage(theTile, 32*(i%8),32*(i/8), this);
```

Comment: By dear... you just SOLVED it! That's logic thinking right there. I'm not good with Math since it's not my strong point... but THANK you. You got it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Right here: `g.drawImage(theTile, 32*i,32*i, this);`  So on the element when i = 2, you're tell it "Two out, Two down".  The third element prints "Three out, Three down".  I don't know why you're not using a two dimensional array, but to make it work with a one dimensional array I suppose you could do:

```
g.drawImage(theTile, 32*(i%8),32*(i/8), this);
```

Comment: What's the point in using a two-dimensional array? I mean... why.

Comment: Suppose it depends on your goal.  If you're moving a checker, would you like to say, "It's at 1,1, legal moves are 2,2 and 2,0" or "It's at 9, legal moves are 16 and 18"  I realize now that you're not actually using it as a gameboard, but if you plan to manipulate it at all after drawing it, it would probably still prove much easier to work with.